# How to know the popped state of a NavigationPage in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want it to popup or not to popup by receiving the On and Off events.

I received the On event and popped it up. Off event has [await Navigation.PopAllPopupAsync(false); ] to clear the popup.

There are cases where the off event comes in twice. If there is no currently popped page, await Navigation.PopAllPopupAsync(false); will throw an exception. So I want to know if there is a flag to know if there is currently popped screen.

How to know which page is currently popped up

Comment: I don't think `PopAllPopupAsync` is a NavigationPage method. Is this Rg.Plugins.Popup? Add to question, xaml or code that makes the popup show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix #1:**

You could make the exception harmless:

```cs
    try
    {
      await Navigation.PopAllPopupAsync(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

---

**Fix #2:**

You could keep track of it yourself:

```cs
public static bool PopupIsShowing;


  // In On event, Just before (or just after) you show it.
  PopupIsShowing = true;


  // In Off event,
  if (PopupIsShowing) {
    PopupIsShowing = false;
    await Navigation.PopAllPopupAsync(false);
  }
```

Comment: I ended up adding a flag to the class the way you recommended.